# Vimeo pro authentication php

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to authenticate `VIMEOPRO` using `VIMEOPRO API`  in php. I add `vimeo.php`file in my `index.php` and create a object of `PhpVimeo` class.

> Below is my code

```
<?php
 require_once('vimeo.php');
 session_start();
 $vimeo = new phpVimeo('Customer key', 'Seceret key');
 $token = $vimeo->getRequestToken();
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($token);
 die;
?>
```

> Below is my error

[image: Signature error]

> I also trying `VIMEOPRO PHP` plugin but another error occur

[image: Error]

and last there is difference b/w `client id` and `client secret key`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`phpVimeo` is the old, deprecated library (as mentioned in the readme: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib#readme)

Use the new php library: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php with your `client_id` and `client_secret`.

For more information on generating authentication, check the docs: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#generate-your-access-token

Comment: I have one another question can you help me ? my question is i have to upload video from admin panel of my domain and the size of the video is large around 500 MB what is the best way 1) Jquery 2) Form submit, if you have any link from video upload please share.. thanks

Comment: This is a good client side uploader script: https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload

Comment: error occur while uploading video `The user is not allowed to perform that action.`  in console =>`POST https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: You should reach out to vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact. Send them some example code and the tokens you are using and they can help you out